# can iphone use as a receiver?

Tags: iphone, rdf

Can iphone use as a receiver ? Let's say, there will be one app which can connect with a hardware that can send RDF signal. Is that possible iphone to receive signal without any additional hardware ? Thanks.

Comment: I presume that by RDF you mean "Radio Direction Finder" and not "Resource Description Framework"

Comment: yes, radio direction finder. Sorry about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible without any additional hardware.

In order to make peripherals work with iPhone you need to contact Apple and become a registered peripheral developer, the membership that allows manufacturers to use the "Made for iPhone" etc labels.

Once you're a member you can get access to the peripherals SDK which allows you to develop for devices that connect to the iPhone using the 30 pin dock connector.

Without developing a device that receives RDF signal that can connect to the iPhone either using the dock connector or a network connection, there's no other way to make the iPhone receive that signal.

Answer (score 0):

If the RDF hardware is able to communicate using standard UDP or TCP/IP based methods then the iPhone can communicate with it using network communication classes. This could be CFNetwork or higher level classes such as NSURLConnection.

Comment: thanks for the answer Broch. If hardware does not support UDP , TCP/IP, there's no way for iphone to directly receive RDF signal ?